# Best way to update view count in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

My client has a table that tracks total views for each of his articles.  The problem is they want me to break the view count into days.  I can easily enough query the db and grab the view counts, but I'm unsure of how to grab each days view count (for each article of course).

In case I'm not being clear (which is usually the case I've been told) I have a field in a table that collects all views on each article with no regard to date or time.  If the article was viewed, the row is plus one'd.  Look at the record a year from now and the view count shows 2,000.  That's it.

What I want to do is capture each days view count for each article and plunk that into its own table but I CANNOT impact said view count field/record.  This way, the client can view each days view count on each article. Any idea on the best approach?

I hope that all made sense!!

Comment: There is no one best way. And you did not provide any table structure, example data or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would make a new table for views and insert a new record on each view and when was it viewed, then I would select all the views that are dated today and count them and that would give me the number of times the article was viewed today and it would still keep the total count

Comment: This is what I would recommend. When you record data to be used on any kind of report, it's always best to record it as raw as possible. If you record data like that, summing 1 to a recorded total, you will be in a bad situation in the future, when your customer asks to view the data in a different way. So, keep it as raw as possible: that will give you all flexibility to change the way reports are presented.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `daily_views` SET `views` = 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `views_table` 
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-06-10' 
    AND '2013-06-11'
    AND `post_id` = 1
, `post_id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start at New Year Eve. Each day take the count and store it in a separate table. On the next day subtract current count with the stored one - this is yesterday's count - store the difference on another table together with the date. So, clear or not?